# Datetime picker directive with range

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

help me to create a Directive in angularJs for datetime picker with date as range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [pikaday angular directive](http://nverba.github.io/pikaday-angular/) as date picker which using pikaday js plugins